# I need to make a rule of 3, but I necessarily need to divide by zero

Tags: analysis

I have a `scrollbar` on my web page, and my problem is the following:

I have a function that allows me to do this: I can specify a time in milliseconds and it will be the `total duration` of how long it takes for my `scrollbar` to reach the bottom of the page.

In my case I want this animation to take `15` seconds, so the `duration = 15000ms`
on the other hand, the total `height` of my web page is `1874`, so if the `scrollbar` is in position `0`, the duration must be `15000ms` since it will take `15000ms` before it reaches the end of my web page. if the `scrollbar` position is `1874` obviously the duration in milliseconds will be `0ms` because it has already reached the end.

I don't know how to do this `rule of 3` and I'm trying this rule to get `x`:

```
0 (initial position)              15000 (duration)
937 (current value of scrollbar)   x

(15000 * 937  /   0 )= ERROR
```

how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Being in position $x$ is equivalent with needing to scroll down $1874-x$ units(cm, pixels or whatever). So with the new formulation, the duration will be $t = (1874-x)*15000/1874$. The last equation is basically $time = distance / speed$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "velocity"-factor to calculate  the time to reach the height of $937$

$$\textrm{Millisecond per pixel}=\frac{15000}{1874}$$

So the time to reach the height of $937$, starting from $1874$, is $\frac{15000}{1874}\cdot (1874-937)=7500 \ (\textrm{milliseconds)}$

So the general formula is $ms(x)=\frac{15000}{1874}\cdot (1874-x)$

Comment: thanks for answering, so  `(1874 * 15000)  *  937 (current value)` ? if the current value of the scrollbar is zero, the value must be 15000, if the current value of the scrollbar is 1874, the value must be 0. I don't know if I'm understanding you correctly

Comment: No, didn´t recognize that it is the other way round. You start at 1874 and the end is 0. I´ve corrected my formula. But your statements are right: $ms(0)=15000, ms(1874)=0$